# Imported mesh from maya looks off

Tags: modeling, axis

hello guys can someone help here, pretty new to blender, currently imported a polygon hair mesh from maya to blender and this happens, looks like all the points are stuck on the center axis

[image]

Comment: what format do you use ? can you share your mesh ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Re-exporting the file as an ***Alembic*** helped solve the problem instead of an ***FBX***.